# Automatic Voice Recording when Voice starts

Tags: ios, audio-recording, voice-recording

i am looking for a source or tutorial that does show how to automatic start recording when voice starts and stop when speech ends.

till now i do it by a simple volume peak level. the problem appears that the first 1-2 secs are often missed. guess would need kind a buffer.

thank you.